# Sign of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to understand the sign of the following integral, where $x \in [l,u]$ and it is drawn from the continuous distribution $\zeta(x)$ over the same interval. $\gamma$ and $\tau$ are parameters in (0,1), and $s$ is the variable of integration.

\begin{equation*} \label{eq.der.alpha}
\int_{x}^{u} s [1-\zeta(s)]^{\frac{1-\tau}{\gamma}} \big[1 + \frac{1 - \tau}{\gamma}(\log \frac{1-\zeta(s)}{1-\zeta(x)})\big] d\zeta(s)
\end{equation*}

I know that a point $s^* \in [x,u]$ (with $x \geq l$) that divides the integral in two parts (one positive and one negative) exists. My problem is that as the integrating variable $s$ gets closer to $u$ in the fraction in parenthesis, the logarithm goes to $-\infty$, so that the integral may not be well defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment rather than an answer.
I'm trying to simplify the expressions.

I start with renaming the variables
to easier to enter ones
and proceed from there.

$\begin{array}\\
f(x, u)
&=\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{\frac{1-t}{g}} \big[1 + \frac{1 - t}{g}(\log \frac{1-z(s)}{1-z(x)})\big] dz(s)\\
&=\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r} \big[1 + r(\log \frac{1-z(s)}{1-z(x)})\big] dz(s)
\qquad\text{where } r = \frac{1-t}{g}\\
&=\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r}  dz(s)
+r\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r} (\log \frac{1-z(s)}{1-z(x)}) dz(s)\\
&= I_1 + rI_2\\
\text{where}\\
I_1
&=\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r}  dz(s)\\
\text{and}\\
I_2
&=\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r} (\log \frac{1-z(s)}{1-z(x)}) dz(s)\\
\end{array}
$

$I_2$
can be split in two ways.

The first:

$\begin{array}\\
I_2
&=\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r} (\log \frac{1-z(s)}{1-z(x)}) dz(s)\\
&=\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r} (\log (1-z(s))) dz(s)
-\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r} (\log (1-z(x))) dz(s)\\
&=\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r} (\log (1-z(s))) dz(s)
-\log (1-z(x))\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r}  dz(s)\\
\end{array}
$

and that second integral
is the same as in $I_1$.

The second:

Using
$\frac{1-z(s)}{1-z(x)}
=\frac{1-z(x)+z(x)-z(s)}{1-z(x)}
=1+\frac{z(x)-z(s)}{1-z(x)}
$
we get

$\begin{array}\\
I_2
&=\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r} (\log \frac{1-z(s)}{1-z(x)}) dz(s)\\
&=\int_{x}^{u} s [1-z(s)]^{r} \log (1+\frac{z(x)-z(s)}{1-z(x)}) dz(s)\\
\end{array}
$

and this might be useful
where
$x$ is close to $s$.

I'll leave it at this,
and hope that this can help
someone else.